# Not complete sentence

Tags: sentence

Is it okay for Standard American English to use incomplete sentences?Like:
Allow yourself time. (it is not said for what)

Comment: As it is said in Cambridge dictionary, this phrase needs  objects:     He didn't allow us enough time to finish the test.It is never used without objects in any dictionary, so it may be not Standard English,  I don't know how to prove that this sentence is correct or not correct

Comment: Thank you!What if it was not the imperative form?Like" They do not allow enough time ".Would it be grammatically correct?

Comment: The verb allow can be used as an imperative or not.